# Missing packets (Windows NDIS Driver Filter)

Tags: c, windows, networking, driver, ndis

I'm a beginner to WDD. I need to make a network driver filter that drops certain packets based on the signature to protect system from program vulnerability.
Right now, I'm just trying to get the packets I need and find my signature. I use Metasploit Framework to exploit this vulnerability and Wireshark to track the traffic. In Wireshark I see 4 packets with destination port 8000 like this:

[image: Traffic picture]
But when I'm trying to get them I only have 2 first of them - with SYN and ACK.
My code is based on [NDIS driver filter sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/network/ndis/filter). I'm writing inside the FilterReceiveNetBufferLists function. Here's the code:

```
_Use_decl_annotations_
VOID
FilterReceiveNetBufferLists(
    NDIS_HANDLE         FilterModuleContext,
    PNET_BUFFER_LIST    NetBufferLists,
    NDIS_PORT_NUMBER    PortNumber,
    ULONG               NumberOfNetBufferLists,
    ULONG               ReceiveFlags
)
/*++

Routine Description:

    FilerReceiveNetBufferLists is an optional function for filter drivers.
    If provided, this function processes receive indications made by underlying
    NIC or lower level filter drivers. This function  can also be called as a
    result of loopback. If this handler is NULL, NDIS will skip calling this
    filter when processing a receive indication and will call the next higher
    driver in the stack. A filter that doesn't provide a
    FilterReceiveNetBufferLists handler cannot provide a
    FilterReturnNetBufferLists handler and cannot a initiate an original receive
    indication on its own.

Arguments:

    FilterModuleContext      - our filter context area.
    NetBufferLists           - a linked list of NetBufferLists
    PortNumber               - Port on which the receive is indicated
    ReceiveFlags             -

N.B.: It is important to check the ReceiveFlags in NDIS_TEST_RECEIVE_CANNOT_PEND.
    This controls whether the receive indication is an synchronous or
    asynchronous function call.

--*/
{

    PMS_FILTER          pFilter = (PMS_FILTER)FilterModuleContext;
    BOOLEAN             DispatchLevel;
    ULONG               Ref;
    BOOLEAN             bFalse = FALSE;
#if DBG
    ULONG               ReturnFlags;
#endif

    DEBUGP(DL_TRACE, "===>ReceiveNetBufferList: NetBufferLists = %p.\n", NetBufferLists);
    do
    {

        DispatchLevel = NDIS_TEST_RECEIVE_AT_DISPATCH_LEVEL(ReceiveFlags);
#if DBG
        FILTER_ACQUIRE_LOCK(&pFilter->Lock, DispatchLevel);

        if (pFilter->State != FilterRunning)
        {
            FILTER_RELEASE_LOCK(&pFilter->Lock, DispatchLevel);

            if (NDIS_TEST_RECEIVE_CAN_PEND(ReceiveFlags))
            {
                ReturnFlags = 0;
                if (NDIS_TEST_RECEIVE_AT_DISPATCH_LEVEL(ReceiveFlags))
                {
                    NDIS_SET_RETURN_FLAG(ReturnFlags, NDIS_RETURN_FLAGS_DISPATCH_LEVEL);
                }

                NdisFReturnNetBufferLists(pFilter->FilterHandle, NetBufferLists, ReturnFlags);
            }
            break;
        }
        FILTER_RELEASE_LOCK(&pFilter->Lock, DispatchLevel);
#endif

        ASSERT(NumberOfNetBufferLists >= 1);

        ////////////////////////////// MY CODE //////////////////////////////////////

        FILTER_ACQUIRE_LOCK(&pFilter->Lock, DispatchLevel);

        PNET_BUFFER_LIST pCurrentNetBufferList = NetBufferLists;
        PNET_BUFFER pCurrentNetBuffer = NET_BUFFER_LIST_FIRST_NB(pCurrentNetBufferList);

        while (pCurrentNetBufferList)
        {
            while (pCurrentNetBuffer)
            {
                ULONG netbuffer_size = NET_BUFFER_DATA_LENGTH(pCurrentNetBuffer);

                BYTE* buffer = (BYTE*)NdisGetDataBuffer(
                    pCurrentNetBuffer,
                    netbuffer_size,
                    NULL,
                    1,
                    0);

                if (buffer) {
                    ParseBuffer(buffer, netbuffer_size);
                }
                else
                {
                    void* alloc_mem = ExAllocatePoolWithTag(PagedPool, netbuffer_size, 'BteN');

                    buffer = (BYTE*)NdisGetDataBuffer(
                        pCurrentNetBuffer,
                        netbuffer_size,
                        alloc_mem,
                        1,
                        0);

                    if (buffer) {
                        ParseBuffer(buffer, netbuffer_size);
                    }
                    else {
                        DbgPrint("T.T");
                    }

                    ExFreePoolWithTag(alloc_mem, 'BteN');
                }

                pCurrentNetBuffer = NET_BUFFER_NEXT_NB(pCurrentNetBuffer);
            }

            pCurrentNetBufferList = NET_BUFFER_LIST_NEXT_NBL(pCurrentNetBufferList);
        }

        FILTER_RELEASE_LOCK(&pFilter->Lock, DispatchLevel);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        //
        // If you would like to drop a received packet, then you must carefully
        // modify the NBL chain as follows:
        //
        //     if NDIS_TEST_RECEIVE_CANNOT_PEND(ReceiveFlags):
        //         For each NBL that is NOT dropped, temporarily unlink it from
        //         the linked list, and indicate it up alone with 
        //         NdisFIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists and the
        //         NDIS_RECEIVE_FLAGS_RESOURCES flag set.  Then immediately
        //         relink the NBL back into the chain.  When all NBLs have been
        //         indicated up, you may return from this function.
        //     otherwise (NDIS_TEST_RECEIVE_CANNOT_PEND is FALSE):
        //         Divide the linked list of NBLs into two chains: one chain
        //         of packets to drop, and everything else in another chain.
        //         Return the first chain with NdisFReturnNetBufferLists, and
        //         indicate up the rest with NdisFIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists.
        //
        // Note: on the receive path for Ethernet packets, one NBL will have 
        // exactly one NB.  So (assuming you are receiving on Ethernet, or are 
        // attached above Native WiFi) you do not need to worry about dropping
        // one NB, but trying to indicate up the remaining NBs on the same NBL.
        // In other words, if the first NB should be dropped, drop the whole NBL.
        //

        //
        // If you would like to modify a packet, and can do so quickly, you may
        // do it here.  However, make sure you save enough information to undo
        // your modification in the FilterReturnNetBufferLists handler.
        //

        //
        // If necessary, queue the NetBufferLists in a local structure for later
        // processing.  However, do not queue them for "too long", or else the
        // system's performance may be degraded.  If you need to hold onto an
        // NBL for an unbounded amount of time, then allocate memory, perform a
        // deep copy, and return the original NBL.
        //

        if (pFilter->TrackReceives)
        {
            FILTER_ACQUIRE_LOCK(&pFilter->Lock, DispatchLevel);
            pFilter->OutstandingRcvs += NumberOfNetBufferLists;
            Ref = pFilter->OutstandingRcvs;

            FILTER_LOG_RCV_REF(1, pFilter, NetBufferLists, Ref);
            FILTER_RELEASE_LOCK(&pFilter->Lock, DispatchLevel);
        }

        NdisFIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists(
            pFilter->FilterHandle,
            NetBufferLists,
            PortNumber,
            NumberOfNetBufferLists,
            ReceiveFlags);


        if (NDIS_TEST_RECEIVE_CANNOT_PEND(ReceiveFlags) &&
            pFilter->TrackReceives)
        {
            FILTER_ACQUIRE_LOCK(&pFilter->Lock, DispatchLevel);
            pFilter->OutstandingRcvs -= NumberOfNetBufferLists;
            Ref = pFilter->OutstandingRcvs;
            FILTER_LOG_RCV_REF(2, pFilter, NetBufferLists, Ref);
            FILTER_RELEASE_LOCK(&pFilter->Lock, DispatchLevel);
        }

    } while (bFalse);

    DEBUGP(DL_TRACE, "<===ReceiveNetBufferList: Flags = %8x.\n", ReceiveFlags);

}
```

ParseBuffer function:

```
VOID ParseBuffer(BYTE *buffer, ULONG netbuffer_size)
{
    // parse ethernet
    eth_header_t* pEthHeader = (eth_header_t*)buffer;
    ASSERT(pEthHeader);

    if (pEthHeader->type == RtlUshortByteSwap(EtherType_IPv4))
    {
        // parse ipv4
        ipv4_header_t* pIpHeader = (ipv4_header_t*)(buffer + sizeof(eth_header_t));
        ASSERT(pIpHeader);
        ASSERT(pIpHeader->version == IPPROTO_IPV4);

        if (pIpHeader->protocol == IPPROTO_TCP)
        {
            // parse tcp
            tcp_header_t* pTcpHeader = (tcp_header_t*)(buffer + sizeof(eth_header_t) + sizeof(ipv4_header_t));
            ASSERT(pTcpHeader);

            if (pTcpHeader->dst_port == RtlUshortByteSwap(8000))
            {
                if (netbuffer_size) {}

                DbgPrint("PACKET DUMP:\n");
                DbgPrintHexDump(buffer, netbuffer_size);

                WORD ip_total_length = RtlUshortByteSwap(pIpHeader->total_length);
                WORD tcp_size = ip_total_length - sizeof(ipv4_header_t);
                WORD data_size = tcp_size - (pTcpHeader->data_offset << 2);

                DbgPrint("DATA SIZE: %d \n", data_size);

                // if there is any data in packet
                if(data_size)
                {
                    BYTE* data = (buffer + sizeof(eth_header_t) + sizeof(ipv4_header_t) + (pTcpHeader->data_offset << 2));
                    ASSERT(data);

                    DbgPrint("Data:\n");
                    DbgPrintHexDump(data, data_size);

                    const char* signature = "\xEB\x0C / HTTP/1.1 ";
                    const char* pch = strstr((const char*)data, signature);
                    if (pch != NULL)
                    {
                        DbgPrint("Got it!\n");
                    }
                }

                DbgPrint("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe I have to clone NetBufferLists before processing them, I don't know. And if I have to, when should I do it?

P.S. [The full code](https://github.com/Airy-Fairy/ndis-driver-filter/blob/master/filter.c) (if you need).

Comment: And how exactly are you "dropping" packets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It was a stupid mistake, I put `PNET_BUFFER pCurrentNetBuffer = NET_BUFFER_LIST_FIRST_NB(pCurrentNetBufferList)` in the wrong place. It has to be right after `while (pCurrentNetBufferList)`.